# Missing node_modules when deploying AngularJS2 application to Bluemix

Tags: npm, ibm-cloud, pipeline

We're trying to deploy an AngularJS2 application to bluemix but we're missing the folder "node_modules" after the application was deployed to the server. We're using npm to build the application.

I found the following post that is mentioning the problem: (https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/181207/npm-install-within-subdirectory-not-creating-node.html)

My question would now be: what's the recommended best practice?

Comment: Johannes, can you include the link to the related post? Also, it would help to add tags for AngularJS and any other service or technology you are using.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the steps you're taking? What is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can recreate problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are installing the node modules using `npm install`, you also should save those module in your `package.json` file which you can do that by `npm install --save`.

The recommended best practice would be to [Setup a Build Pipeline](https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials/basicbuild/).

There could be 3 stages or more:

- Build Stage: It builds the app so doing things like `npm install` there so your folder `node_modules` gets created for you.
- Test Stage: Tests the app so doing things like `npm test` would run all the tests in your app
- Deploy Stage: Once build and deploy stage runs successfully, Deploy will actually deploy the app to the Bluemix domain.